# fabricjs itext is support unicode? (Hangeul not moified)

Tags: javascript, canvas, unicode, encoding, fabricjs

Fabric.js is very cool, but IText has some problem...

I'm Korean, I want to edit Hangeul

```
function insertItext(){
    var text = new fabric.IText('한글',{
        top:100,
        left:100,   
    })  

    text.setFontFamily('바탕체');
    canvas.add(text);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

fontFamily is modified

index.html
text "한글" OK, but not edit text.

i want to edit "한글입니다"
but modified "한글dlqslek"

someone help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also Korean who ran into the same issue with Fabric's iText. I looked at the source code and located the cause.

Fabric IText relies on 'onKeypress' event on textarea to parse and render each character. **Typing Korean character does not trigger onKeypress.** Even if it did, the logic takes no account of languages where you need to type multiple characters to form a single letter.

Your best option is to contribute to the open source or just use Text and create your own textarea to mitigate the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using html input tag.

HTML

```
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.canvas-wrappter {
    position: relative;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.itext {
    width: 300px;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var SINGLE_LINE = false;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// custom input area
if (SINGLE_LINE) {
    var $itext = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('itext');
}
else {
    var $itext = $('<textarea/>').addClass('itext');
}

var text = 'enter multi-byte text here 日本語';
var itext = new fabric.IText(text, {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fontSize: 20,
    fill: '#000'
})
.on('editing:entered', function(e) {
    var obj = this;
    if (SINGLE_LINE) {
        var keyDownCode = 0;
    }

    canvas.remove(obj);

    // show input area
    $itext.css({
        left: obj.left,
        top: obj.top,
        'line-height': obj.lineHeight,
        'font-family': obj.fontFamily,
        'font-size': Math.floor(obj.fontSize * Math.min(obj.scaleX, obj.scaleY)) + 'px',
        'font-weight': obj.fontWeight,
        'font-style': obj.fontStyle,
        color: obj.fill
    })
    .val(obj.text)
    .appendTo($(canvas.wrapperEl).closest('.canvas-wrapper'));

    // text submit event
    if (SINGLE_LINE) {
        // submit text by ENTER key
        $itext.on('keydown', function(e) {
            // save the key code of a pressed key while kanji conversion (it differs from the code for keyup)
            keyDownCode = e.which;
        })
        .on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.which == keyDownCode) {
                obj.exitEditing();
                obj.set('text', $(this).val());
                $(this).remove();
                canvas.add(obj);
                canvas.renderAll();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // submit text by focusout
        $itext.on('focusout', function(e) {
            obj.exitEditing();
            obj.set('text', $(this).val());
            $(this).remove();
            canvas.add(obj);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }

    // focus on text
    setTimeout(function() {
        $itext.select();
    }, 1);
});
canvas.add(itext);
canvas.setActiveObject(itext);
//itext.selectAll();
//itext.enterEditing();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3jk3jvy7/